# Advanced installer adding version number to dialog and final exe

Tags: c#, advanced-installer

I am currently syncing the version number from my binary so the installer ends up with the same version number. I am using the Advanced Installer and got the professional trial version atm.

However at the moment I end up with an exe XXXXSetup.exe and there is no way for someone to know what version it is even after launching it without looking at file properties.

How can I append the version number to the exe filename and also display it somewhere in the installer dialog?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the version in the setup name, you can go in the **Builds** view and in the EXE name field you can add a reference as:
[|ProductName] - [|ProductVersion]

During Build operation, the ProductName and ProductVersion will be set to their values from the project.

By default for all dialogs the title is set to:

> [ProductName] [Setup]

So, if you also want to include the product version in title, then you can go to "Custom Actions" page and add a "Set installer property" custom action with sequence, scheduled after "Wizard Dialogs Stage -> Searches" action group, like this:

- Property: Setup
- Value: Setup [ProductVersion]